# NoReverseMatch at /colorsets/new/ Reverse for 'user_logout' not found. 'user_logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error when trying to click on the "New Color Set" button:

```
NoReverseMatch at /colorsets/new/
Reverse for 'user_logout' not found. 'user_logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I've looked extensively through StackOverflow and elsewhere on other sites and can't seem to find what the issue is. As far a I can tell all my code is right but clearly there is an issue.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Colors</title>

        <meta name"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="uft-8">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    </head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="btn" href="{% url 'colorsets:new_color' %}">New Color Set</a>
                <a class="btn" href="{% url 'accounts:user_logout' %}">Logout</a>
            {% else %}
                <a class="btn" href="{% url 'accounts:user_login' %}">Login</a>
                <a class="btn" href="{% url 'accounts:register' %}">Register</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from accounts.forms import UserForm

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account now active")

        else:
            print("Login Unsuccessful")
            return HttpResponse("Your username and/or password are not correct")

    else:
        return render(request,'accounts/login.html',{})

def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)

            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()

    return render(request,'accounts/register.html',{'user_form':user_form,'registered':registered})

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

accounts app urls.py

    from django.conf.urls import url
    from accounts import views

    app_name = 'accounts'

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register'),
        url(r'^login/$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
        url(r'^logout/',views.user_logout,name='user_logout'),
    ]
```

project urls.py

```
"""colors URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from accounts import views
from colorsets import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
     url(r'^colorsets/',include('colorsets.urls',namespace='colorsets')),
]
```

Let me know if you need to see anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the template under the url named `new_color` in your `colorsets` namespace. You definitely used it as `{% url 'user_logout' %}`, while you should use it like `{% url 'accounts:user_logout' %}`. Just add the namespace.

Comment: I only see one reference to the `user_logout` url in the template, and it already has the namespace in it.

Comment: I only have one use of `user_logout` (in my base.html) and it does have the namespace "accounts"

Comment: Yes, because the problem appears when you're trying to reach the `/colorsets/new/` page which is basically in your `colorsets` django app. You should search an url in the colorsets/urls.py named `new_color`. Then find the corresponding template, in that template you should find wrong reversed url `{% url 'user_logout' %}` and change it to `{% url 'accounts:user_logout' %}`. If you can't find it yourself, just add that template to the question post.

Answer (score 1):

## Check these two things in your project:

-In settings file you should have these two codes

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

-Must have a path in project's urls.py file (as shown below)

```
path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Comment: I have a doubt, this implementation will only work when we are using the default user model that comes from `django.contrib.auth.urls` or `django.db` and it will not work if we are using our own implemented custom user model implemented with something like `AbstractBaseUser` am I right?